# Add "-I" flag to string of paths in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Having a string of space separated paths, relative or absolute, example:

```
/aaaa/bbbb/ccc /ddas/sdsa/dasd ./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd dsd/dsad/erer/rerer ../dasd/dsad ../../sdasd/sdsd
```

How can I process this in bash in order to prepend every one of these paths with -I? Example output should be:

```
-I/aaaa/bbbb/ccc -I/ddas/sdsa/dasd -I./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd dsd/dsad/erer/rerer -I../dasd/dsad -I../../sdasd/sdsd
```

Thanks

Edit for context:
As some of you may already have guessed, the purpose of this is to prepend folder paths with the -I flag for gcc commands.
I'm using this in a makefile. The following (slightly modified from anubhava's suggestion) works perfectly:

```
#to include subdirectories in source
TEMP := $(shell find $(SOURCE_PATH)* -type d)
TEMP := $(shell echo $(TEMP) | awk 1 ORS=' ')
TEMP := $(shell printf -- "-I%s " ${TEMP} )
ifdef TEMP
INC_PATHS += $(TEMP)
endif
```

Comment: In general, it's not safe to assume that none of the paths will themselves contain whitespace.

Comment: You're right. But this just means that I need to figure out a way to first get these paths in between quotation marks. Shouldn't be that hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```
s='/aaaa/bbbb/ccc /ddas/sdsa/dasd ./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd dsd/dsad/erer/rerer ../dasd/dsad ../../sdasd/sdsd'

printf -v output -- "-I%s " $s
echo "$output"
-I/aaaa/bbbb/ccc -I/ddas/sdsa/dasd -I./dasd/dsd -Idasd/dsda/dsd -Idsd/dsad/erer/rerer -I../dasd/dsad -I../../sdasd/sdsd
```

Or if using an array:

```
arr=(/aaaa/bbbb/ccc /ddas/sdsa/dasd ./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd dsd/dsad/erer/rerer ../dasd/dsad ../../sdasd/sdsd)
printf -v output -- "-I%s " "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the paths in an array:

```
paths=(/aaaa/bbbb/ccc /ddas/sdsa/dasd ./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd dsd/dsad/erer/rerer ../dasd/dsad ../../sdasd/sdsd)
```

then you can use bash's find-and-replace syntax:

```
includes=("${paths[@]/#/-I}")
```

You can provide an array as a series of arguments to a command (or function):

```
compile $the_file "${includes[@]}"
```

You can do a similar transform on `$@` (in quotes) in a bash function

```
with_includes() {
  # If you need to do something with the first few arguments,
  # collect them here and then call shift:
  #    the_file=$1; shift
  # But you need to check $# to make sure the arguments exist :)
  local includes=("{@/#/-I}")
  compile $the_file "${includes[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

echo "/aaaa/bbbb/ccc /ddas/sdsa/dasd ./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd dsd/dsad/erer/rerer ../dasd/dsad ../../sdasd/sdsd" | \
sed s'/ / -I/'g
```

I agree with the others that this is bad form, however.  Your paths should ideally be on a seperate line.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

echo "/aaaa/bbbb/ccc /ddas/sdsa/dasd ./dasd/dsd dasd/dsda/dsd \
dsd/dsad/erer/rerer ../dasd/dsad ../../sdasd/sdsd" | \
tr ' ' '\n' > tempfile

let "lines=$(wc -l tempfile | cut -d' ' -f1)"
let "lines=lines+1"
let "counter=1"

function loop() {
[ "${counter}" -lt "${lines}" ] && \
echo "Current loop iteration: ${counter}." && \
sed -n "${counter}p" tempfile | sed s'@^@ -I@'g >> tempfile2 && \
let "counter=counter+1" && \
loop
}

loop

[ -f ./tempfile ] && \
echo "File exists: ./tempfile." && \
rm ./tempfile

[ ! -f ./tempfile ] && \
echo "File deleted: ./tempfile."
```

Then you can just edit the beginning of each line in tempfile2 to do whatever, and run it as a shell script.

Inb4 "Oh God no, he's using test!  That could accidentally create an infinite loop!  WE'RE ALL GOING TO DIE!"

Infinite loops aren't the end of the world.  The worst it will cause is a segfault.  Occasionally they can even be useful.  OP, you will need to make sure you include "&& \" (without quotes) at the end of every command within a test block though; except for the last one of course.

I learned to do it this way because I've spent time in <strike>Sparta</strike> OpenBSD, where rm and most other utilities don't have -v flags, and we also aren't afraid of infinite loops. ;)